# Peek and Pop leaking the mainWindow.rootViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, memory-leaks, peek-pop

When I use 3D Touch to Peek and Pop a view controller, my app `UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window??.rootViewController` is retained by Apple `_UIFullScreenPresentationController`

So if I switch the rootViewController, the old one is never released.

I made a demo app to help understanding : 
https://github.com/rapinto/PeekAndPopLeak

step to reproduce :

- 3d touch on the background of the root `ViewController` to push a new `ViewController`.
- Press the button to swich the app `rootViewController`
- Open the Debug Memory Graph Xcode tool : there are now 2 living `ViewController`
- Optional : if you repeat step 1 to 3, more `ViewController` are leaked

Unregistering the previewing context doesn't solve it.

[image][image]

Anyone can help me?

PS: If you don't peek and pop to push the second `ViewController`, `rootViewController` isn't retained/leaked